# JPA query using named parameter from a oneToOne joined table

Tags: jpa, join

I am trying to create a query that references fields in the WHERE from both the current table and a table joined on a column.  I have no problems creating a query from a single parameter in the Participation table.

```
@NamedQuery(name="Participation.byUserID", query="SELECT c FROM Participation c WHERE c.userID = :userID")
```

Here is the fun part... Within the Participation entity, I have a join:

```
@OneToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "EventID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Event event;
```

The Event entity has some fields I would like to use in my query.  For example, eventDate or eventType.

I am wanting something like WHERE Participation.userID = 123 AND Event.eventType = "meeting" using JPA queries instead of SQL.  How can I expand the simple named query above to include comparisons from the joined table?
So far I have not been able to get this working, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really simple requirement, I suggest you go through some basic JPA tutorials.

```
SELECT c FROM Participation c WHERE c.userID = :userID and c.event.eventType = :eventType
```

Comment: Thank you, I did read several tutorials, just did not come across this combination...  thank you!